# Linq Statement In vb

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am new to vb well not new but used chsarp for years I cant figure out what's wrong with this statement. The debugger is not even hitting the return list part so I don't no what is up. I am using the same context to add files so i don't think its the way i declared it

```
Private threeSoftwareContext As New R3DeliveryEntities1


Public Function GetAlLFilesToBeProcessedByLocation(location As Int32, status As StatusTypes) As List(Of downloadedFile)

    Dim list As New List(Of downloadedFile)
    list = (From files In threeSoftwareContext.downloadedFiles Where files.location = 0 And files.status = status).ToList()
    Return list
End Function
```

Exception message[image]

i got it working with this  but what i dont no in vb is how do I give it columns names

```
 Dim retVal As List(Of downloadedFile)
    Try
        retVal = (From files In threeSoftwareContext.downloadedFiles Where  files.location = 0).ToList()


        Return retVal
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

    Return retVal
```

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: @Steve added the exception above

Comment: What does your `downloadedFile` class look like?  Is `StatusTypes` just an `Enum`?

Comment: @MARK I GOT IT WORK WITH  retVal = (From files In threeSoftwareContext.downloadedFiles Where files.location = 0).ToList()

But i dunno how do I give columns names using this?

Comment: Your edit just seems to drop the check for status, which doesn't really seem to be what you would want.  Not sure what you are asking here: "how do I give columns names using this?".  The missing information from the question is what the `downloadedFile` and `StatusTypes` classes/enums look like.  How is the `downloadedFile.status` property declared?  Also may need to know what version of Entity Framework and .NET you are using - support for Enums was only added recently, if status is an Enum.